# UpdateAsync Force.com SDK

Tags: c#, update, sdk

I am having a problem with Force.com SDK for C#. the UpdateAsync function is updating Lead owner automatically every time I update any field on the lead. Here's the code that I am using

```
var success = await client.UpdateAsync("Lead", testingLeadId, new { Title = "Testing ", Description = "Testing From a new method" });
```

I used Workbench to check if there is a role that is changing the lead owner when it comes to SF but does not seem like it.

Any Ideas/suggestions ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have any Lead Assignment Rules defined? Is there a default Lead Assignment rule under `Setup > Customize > Leads > Lead Settings`?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Daniel for the response.

The problem is UpdateAsync function has Sforce-Auto-Assign = true which caused the lead owner to be reassigned. This is true for Rest API not Soap.

I am using force.com sdk for C# so there is no way for me to set the header (Sforce-Auto-Assign ) to false.

In my case, I found two solution

1. Rewrite the sdk. To do this please check this link https://github.com/nmonasterio/Force.com-Toolkit-for-NET/blob/cutom-headers/src/ForceToolkitForNET/IForceClient.cs
   This adds the option to call `CreateAsync` and pass additional headers with the request.
2. Add another rule to the rules assignment object to handle this case. So it should look like this

criteria = Current User: 18 Digit User xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
assign to = Same User

The above rule dictate when user X updates the lead records, the lead owner must not change.

Hope this helps!